# Java lottery using arrays and methods

Tags: java

I am getting an error on the file name. it says

```
Main.java:5: error: class LotteryProgram is public, should be declared in a file named LotteryProgram.java
public class LotteryProgram {
       ^
1 error
```

I looked over the code several time and used different compilers and the program worked in one but not the other. Is there actually something wrong with the program? Or do some of the compilers work different?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LotteryProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] lotteryNumbers = generateLotteryNumbers();
        int[] userNumbers = getUserNumbers();
        int matches = countMatches(lotteryNumbers, userNumbers);

        System.out.println("Lottery Numbers: " + Arrays.toString(lotteryNumbers));
        System.out.println("User Numbers: " + Arrays.toString(userNumbers));
        System.out.println("Matches: " + matches);
    }

    public static int[] generateLotteryNumbers() {
        int[] lotteryNumbers = new int[5];
        Random random = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < lotteryNumbers.length; i++) {
            lotteryNumbers[i] = random.nextInt(10); // Generate random numbers between 0 and 9
        }

        return lotteryNumbers;
    }

    public static int[] getUserNumbers() {
        int[] userNumbers = new int[5];
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter your lottery numbers (between 0 and 9):");

        for (int i = 0; i < userNumbers.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Number " + (i + 1) + ": ");
            userNumbers[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        }

        return userNumbers;
    }

    public static int countMatches(int[] lotteryNumbers, int[] userNumbers) {
        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < lotteryNumbers.length; i++) {
            if (lotteryNumbers[i] == userNumbers[i]) {
                count++;
            }
        }

        return count;
    }
}
```

The output should have looked someting like this.

```
java -cp /tmp/bViay8YpR4 LotteryProgram
Enter your lottery numbers (between 0 and 9):
Number 1: 2
Number 2: 8
Number 3: 5
Number 4: 6
Number 5: 7
Lottery Numbers: [6, 6, 0, 0, 5]
User Numbers: [2, 8, 5, 6, 7]
Matches: 0
```

Comment: What is the name of the file that contains your Java source code?  The error is pretty straight forward - `class LotteryProgram is public, should be declared in a file named LotteryProgram.java`.

Comment: I'm going to retag this as this is java not javascript as despite the name they are quite different.

Comment: Either rename `Main.java` to `LotteryProgram.java` OR rename the  `LotteryProgram` class to `Main`, for example: `public class Main {` instead of: `public class LotteryProgram {`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the file name is the same as the *class* name, case matters.

So, it *should* be, "LotteryProgram.java".